# Did the wine jars of Cana overflow on the miracle?

Tags: gospel-of-john, apocrypha, miracles-of-jesus

We see minute details of preparation for the first-ever public miracle of Jesus in John 2:6-7:

> Nearby stood six stone water jars, the kind used by the Jews for ceremonial washing, each holding from twenty to thirty gallons. Jesus said to the servants, “Fill the jars with water”; so they filled them to the brim.

The density of wine is slightly less than that of water, at about 0.99 g/mL. So if you have a standard glass of wine, that's roughly 150 mL, converting that to grams, you're at about 148.5 grams. In other words, 148.5 mL of pure water, if turned into wine, would make 150 mL. Given that each of the six jars had a capacity of 20 to 30 gallons, and each having been filled to the brim, there was all possibility that once the water turned into wine, the jars were no longer able to hold it without spilling.

Now, John the Evangelist has the distinction of having recorded minute details of events, especially miracles. See for example, John 6:12-13:

> When they had all had enough to eat, he said to his disciples, “Gather the pieces that are left over. Let nothing be wasted.”  So they gathered them and filled twelve baskets with the pieces of the five barley loaves left over by those who had eaten.

When John wrote that the jars had been filled 'to the brim 'prior to the miracle, there was some purpose. However, he does not mention if the jars were able to hold the water since miraculously turned into wine. Of course, the guests were desperately waiting for wine, and the jars would soon run dry. So, the phenomenon of overflowing must have been momentary.

Are any apocryphal writings available on the post-miracle wine jars of Cana?

Comment: You have forgotten the evaporation of the azeotrope. And the differing densities of ethanol and water. And the fact that the water in the vessel may still have been water and the sampling of the liquid is when the instant of miracle took place.

Comment: Nigel J, wine makers always leave some space in the bottles before capping them, so as to accommodate increase in volume on account of fermentation.

Comment: ..And look at the literal purport of Mtt 9:14 ,: Neither do people pour new wine into old wineskins. If they do, the skins will burst; the wine will run out and the wineskins will be ruined.

Comment: as long as we are dealing with technicalities, they were not wine jars but water containers.

Comment: Thanks, Dan Fefferman. People of Jesus' time used wineskins which were more sensitive to volume increase. Hence Mtt 9:14 .

Comment: It is a miracle, and miracles are not subject to physical laws, that's what make them  miracles. On a physical base, you could also argue on the number of protons involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Did the wine jars of Cana overflow on the miracle?**

There seems to be no apocryphal writings that state that indicate that the jars at the Wedding Feast at Cana overflowed.

St. John the Apostle was a very sober (no pun intended) writer and wrote as accurate as possible about the events that happened during the public life of Jesus. He states that the jars were filled to the brim with water. Thus the amount of water versus wine were equal. If the wine had overflowed, St. John certainly would have recorded that point.

If the wine had overflowed, that would mean that Jesus not only changed water into wine, but also created more wine than water!!!

> 6 Nearby stood six stone water jars, the kind used by the Jews for ceremonial washing, each holding from twenty to thirty gallons.
>
> 7 Jesus said to the servants, “Fill the jars with water”; so they filled them to the brim. - [John 2:6-7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%202%3A6-7&version=NIV)